# Creating C# bindings

Tags: c#, c++, binding

i have a library written in C++, how can i create bindings to C# so i can expose the functionality of that library to C#?
And i don`t mean "port" (using SWIG possibly). I mean that when calling some functions in C#, pure C++ code is executed so it is fast.
I've searched around in google but i couldn't find anything o_O

Thanks in advance :-)

p.s.: please take into notice, that i'm a bit noob in C#

Comment: Just for the record, SWIG doesn't port code, it generates wrapper functions that let you call C or C++ from another language.  Pure C++ code is still executed, but depending on the exact situation data may be copied when passing parameters in or getting return values out.

Answer (score 2):

I found good library for generating C# bindings called [CppSharp](https://github.com/mono/CppSharp)
This library is generator tool , here is good starting point and tutorial https://github.com/mono/CppSharp/blob/master/docs/GeneratingBindings.md

Answer (score 1):

Try looking here to see if this helps.  You can call unmanaged code from C#. It's not terribly difficult but you need to keep in mind you're working unmanaged.  Coming from a C++ background this shouldn't be too tough to keep in mind.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc301501.aspx